# Maven build error: failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5: deploy (default-deploy) on project pluto

Tags: maven, deployment, pluto

i am trying to deploy a portlet using pluto, But i am getting the following errors:

```
C:\PlutoInstallation\pluto>mvn deploy -Ddeploy=c:\PlutoInstallation\portlets\Hel
loWorldPortlet.war
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-container:bundle:2.0.3
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-container-driver-api:bundle:2.0.3
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-portal-driver:bundle:2.0.3
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-portal-driver-impl:bundle:2.0.3
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-portal:war:2.0.3
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${build.finalName} is deprecated. Please use ${project.
build.finalName} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-testsuite:war:2.0.3
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-
plugin is missing. @ org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-testsuite:[unknown-version],
 C:\PlutoInstallation\pluto\pluto-testsuite\pom.xml, line 91, column 21
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${build.finalName} is deprecated. Please use ${project.
build.finalName} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.build.finalName} is deprecated. Please use ${proj
ect.build.finalName} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.build.finalName} is deprecated. Please use ${proj
ect.build.finalName} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-util:bundle:2.0.3
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:maven-pluto-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0.3
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto-ant-tasks:jar:2.0.3
[WARNING] The expression ${pom.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.vers
ion} instead.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten t
he stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support buildin
g such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Pluto
[INFO] Apache Pluto Container API
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portlet Container
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portlet Tag Library
[INFO] Apache Pluto Container Driver API
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portal Driver
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portal Driver Implementation Classes
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portal
[INFO] Apache Pluto Utilities
[INFO] Maven Pluto Installer Plugin
[INFO] Apache Pluto Testsuite Portlet
[INFO] Apache Pluto Ant Tasks
[INFO] Apache Pluto Website Skin
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Pluto 2.0.3
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:process (default) @ pluto ---
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus
.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- ianal-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-1:verify-legal-files (default) @ pluto -
--
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install) @ pluto ---
[INFO] Installing C:\PlutoInstallation\pluto\pom.xml to C:\Users\svalsalan\.m2\r
epository\org\apache\portals\pluto\pluto\2.0.3\pluto-2.0.3.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) @ pluto ---
Uploading: https://repository.apache.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org
/apache/portals/pluto/pluto/2.0.3/pluto-2.0.3.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Pluto ....................................... FAILURE [  4.907 s]
[INFO] Apache Pluto Container API ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portlet Container ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portlet Tag Library ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Container Driver API .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portal Driver ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portal Driver Implementation Classes .. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Portal ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Utilities ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Maven Pluto Installer Plugin ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Testsuite Portlet ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Ant Tasks ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Pluto Website Skin .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.557 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-18T12:34:17+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/173M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:
deploy (default-deploy) on project pluto: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not
transfer artifact org.apache.portals.pluto:pluto:pom:2.0.3 from/to apache.releas
es.https (https://repository.apache.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2): Fa
iled to transfer file: https://repository.apache.org/service/local/staging/deplo
y/maven2/org/apache/portals/pluto/pluto/2.0.3/pluto-2.0.3.pom. Return code is: 4
01, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
C:\PlutoInstallation\pluto>
```

I am trying to deploy a portlet to the pluto but the build seems to be a failure. Please help. The Maven installation is fine, there are no errors n the installation though.

Answer (score 1):

You try to put the artefact to an apache repo:

```
https://repository.apache.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/org/apache/portals/pluto/pluto/2.0.3/pluto-2.0.3.pom.
```

But you have not the permission to do it:

```
Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

Change to a local repo.

Comment: Thnk u jens, but how to do it? i hve no idea.. pls help